# How to configure Java 7 OR Java 8 dependency in Debian deb package?

Tags: java, linux, debian, deb, dpkg

I am building a Debian *.deb package for our proprietary software.
The software is Java based, so I thought it would be good if the deb package checks for an installed Java package first.

```
Package: [[name]]
Version: [[version]]
Section: non-free
Priority: low
Architecture: all
Description: [[description]]
Maintainer: company <email @ address>
Homepage: http://product.website
Depends: java7-runtime-headless
```

**Problems:**

- This fails if an Oracle JDK 7 is installed. It seems as this would only check for the OpenJDK 7 package. *How can I check for both Java packages, Oracle AND OpenJDK?*
- This fails if OpenJDK 8 is installed but it shouldn't. Our software runs with Java 7 and Java 8. *How can I check for either JDK 7 OR JDK 8?*

Summary: How can I configure the `Depends:` section of my package so `dpkg` checks for ANY Java/JDK package in version 7 or 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for "ANY" Java/JDK package, you can use the pipe symbol ("`|`") in the `Depends:` line. For example, here's the line for the `tomcat7-common` package in Jessie:

```
Depends: libtomcat7-java (>= 7.0.56-3), default-jre-headless | java6-runtime-headless | java6-runtime | java-6-runtime
```

However, note that if you use a `Depends:` line, `dpkg` will only consider it satisfied by packages that it knows about.  If someone installs Oracle Java, or some other vendor's JDK, without using `dpkg`, or if the `.deb` doesn't list the right keywords in a `Provides:` line, it won't work.  So, you might be better off with a `Suggests:` or `Recommends:` line.

Comment: Thanks david! You're right, `Depends:` seems to be too strict. I'll use `Suggests:` instead and encourage the users to manually check their java versions prior to install...